# Formula for result of elastic collision of 2 balls in space

Tags: collision

I have a ball A of radius R1, mass M1 velocity components X1, Y1, Z1, that collides with a ball B of radius R2, mass M2, velocity components X2,Y2 and Z2. I`m told the angles involved (where exactly does a ball hit the other) are crucial for the result I need, but figuring out what *works* will take me forever :) I need an equation that will give me the final velocity components of the 2 balls. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I need an equation" is not a conceptual problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a few tricks to arrive at the formula. If you first assume all motion is on the X-axis (the general case follows from that), the total momentum would be $p_x=M_1X_1+M_2X_2$. Now switch to a frame where the total momentum is zero:
$$X'_1=X_1-p_x/(M_1+M_2)\\X'_2=X_2-p_x/(M_1+M_2)$$
Such that \begin{align}p_x'&=M_1X_1'+M_2X_2'\\&=M_1X_1-M_1p_x/(M_1+M_2)+M_2X_2-M_2p_x/(M_1+M_2)\\&=p_x-(M_1+M_2)\ p_x/(M_1+M_2)\\&=p_x-p_x=0\end{align}
Momentum and energy are both conserved so they are the same before and after the collision. Call the velocities after the collision $(U_1, V_1, W_1)$ and $(U_2, V_2, W_2)$. From the conservation of momentum follows that $M_1X_1'+M_2X_2'=M_1U_1'+M_2U_2'=0$ and from conservation of (kinetic) energy follows that $M_1X_1'^2+M_2X_2'^2=M_1U_1'^2+M_2U_2'^2$. The "obvious" solution is that $$U_1'=-X_1'\\U_2'=-X_2'$$
The velocities simply reflect. This is not true in the original frame!

Now we can go back to our original frame for the final solution:
\begin{align}U_1&=U_1'+p_x/(M_1+M_2)\\&=-X_1'+p_x/(M_1+M_2)\\&=-X_1+2p_x/(M_1+M_2)\end{align}
Substituting $p_x$ and simplifying:
\begin{align}\\U_1&=\frac{-M_1X_1-M_2X_1}{M_1+M_2}+2\frac{M_1X_1+M_2X_2}{M_1+M_2}\\&=\frac{X_1(M_1-M_2)+2M_2X_2}{M_1+M_2}\end{align}
Similarly for $U_2$:
$$U_2=\frac{X_2(M_2-M_1)+2M_1X_1}{M_1+M_2}$$

You can figure out how this works in 3D using the fact that you can split each of the total velocities in two components: one that points in the direction of the other ball (call it $v_{||}$) and another component $v_\perp$. The $v_\perp$ component remains completely unchanged after the collision and for the $v_{||} $component you can use the above formula.

Comment: Elegance! So (Ross Geller comes to mind), because I just skimmed thru (this will be scrutinized with vodka!) and I`ve been wrong before in such cases, I understand that the remaining 4 formulas I need are: V1=Y1(M1-M2)+2M2Y2/M1+M2, V2 & V2=Y2(M2-M1)+2M1Y1/M1+M2 & W1=Z1(M1-M2)+2M2Z2/M1+M2 & W2=Z2(M2-M1)+2M1Z1/M1+M2, right? (My slow brain took this confirmation as a prerequisite to understand what you said  before...). Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

A good approach to this type of collision problems is that instead of solving in the usual Cartesian coordinates, try converting everything into the center of mass frame. That should simplify the mathematics required considerably.